# invalid drawable tag vector in android version 4

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

```
defaultConfig {  
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

I am using this but it is not working.

What is another way to support vector drawable in version 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I just removed the below line from my app gradle and it worked for me in both cases Android version greater than 4 and below. Just one issue is I am getting warning in xml layout file `(To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to set android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true.)` against `app:srcCompat`

```
defaultConfig {  
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true   
}
```

Comment: thanks @Abid Khan its works for me too. thank you so much

Comment: do you have any idea about how can i use drawable background to edit text i am getting issue now in drawable background in edittext version 4? @Abid Khan

Comment: post a new question with the a picture and share the link to that question and I will see what problem are you facing.

Comment: And check for your app on different devices to confirm that's not the issue with the phone DPI